# How to handle mutiple dependency injections in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5

I have one laravel class with more than five dependencies it may increase in future.

I'm getting warning message in **php mess detector** **(CouplingBetweenObjects is more that 13)**

Am i doing this correctly or Is there any better architectures to avoid this.

```
class UserController {
   public function __construct(
        UserRepository $userModel,
        UsersTransformers $usersTransformers,
        GroupRepository $groupModel,
        GroupTransformers $groupTransformers,
        ProjectRepository $projectModel,
        ProjectTransformers $projectTransformers
    ) {
        $this->userModel = $userModel;
        $this->usersTransformers = $usersTransformers;
        $this->groupModel = $groupModel;
        $this->groupTransfromers = $groupTransformers;
        $this->projectModel = $projectModel;
        $this->projectTransformers = $projectTransformers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to inject your Transformers ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I have two function in each transformers for list, view. So I'm injecting that and calling in respective fucntions

Comment: You don't need to! Here's a great approach of how to use transformers :https://www.neontsunami.com/posts/using-fractal-with-laravel-and-lumen

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use constructor injection for all dependencies, you can get them from the IOC container using `App::make('Namespace\Class')`

But having so many dependencies is a smell because it seems like your class is having to many responsibilities. For instance why do the `UserController` need to know about transforming `Groups` and `Projects`? Maybe you instead could use the controllers for those classes and have the controllers abstracting how they are transformed?